# Can i use Direct x 9 in c++ express when i have direct x 11

Tags: c++, express, directx-9

Hi i've got direct x 11 installed and a college course ive just started are using direct x 9. Is there a way to use direct x9 in visual studio express c++ thatnks :)

Comment: I think you should be able to use DX9 even if you have installed DX11 SDK, they are usually backward compatible. You can also use the new DX11 functions, but limit your code to DX9 features.

Comment: Nothing just had a look online to try and find info is there a big diffence between them if i start learning with direct x 11 will it be hard to use direct x 9 at college

Comment: Thanks i wasn't sure never used direct x before :)

Comment: You didn't say which version of Visual C++ Express you are using? Also not that using Direct3D 9 will require using a lot of deprecated stuff like D3DX9, XNAMath, etc. Too bad the course isn't using Direct3D 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use direct-x 9 in Visual Studio Express C++.

You will need to have the correct Direct-X SDK installed, your course should have given you instructions on that. Make sure you install the SDK they ask you to, or code examples they give you may not compile.